AccessGUDID - Unable to Parse the scanned value using BarcodeScanner in canvas app
I need to Parse UDI using AccessGUDID's APIs.

But this doesn't work saying error 400 stating incorrect UDI.
There are plenty of formats available for this - and so far I was able to parse it properly. But for this HIBCC format - I am unable to figure it out.
Below are few quick reference links:

What is UDI?
Understanding UDI formats
HIBCC UDI Label example (for which I am unable to Parse UDI)

Logic I used for other formats is below:
void Main(string UnFormattedAccessGUDID)
{
    var lengthOfAccessGUDID = UnFormattedAccessGUDID.Length;
    var unformattedAccessGUDID = UnFormattedAccessGUDID;

    UnFormattedAccessGUDID.ToString();
    var temp = string.Empty;
    var errorMessage = string.Empty;
    switch (lengthOfAccessGUDID)
    {
        case 16:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            break;
        case 18:
        case 22:
            break;
        case 32:
        case 33:
        case 34:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            if (temp.Substring(18, 2) == "10")  // UDI-SKU-Date format
            {
                temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 18);
                temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 30);
            }
            else if (temp.Substring(18, 2) == "17") // UDI-Date-SKU format
            {
                temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 18);
                temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 28);
            }
            else
            {
                $"Unidentified format '{UnFormattedAccessGUDID}'recieved. Kindly contact admin for a fix.".Dump();
            }
            break;
        case 35:
        case 36:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 18);
            temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 28);
            break;
        case 37:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 18);
            temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 28);
            temp = ParenthesizeLotIdentifier(temp, 39);
            break;
        case 38:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 18);
            temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 28);
            temp = ParenthesizeLotIdentifier(temp, 40);
            break;
        case 39:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 18);
            temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 28);
            temp = ParenthesizeLotIdentifier(temp, 41);
            break;
        case 40:
            temp = ParenthesizeUDI(unformattedAccessGUDID);
            temp = Parenthesize30Identifier(temp, 18);
            temp = ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(temp, 24);
            temp = ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(temp, 34);
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = $"Unable to read the scanned barcode. {unformattedAccessGUDID}(length={lengthOfAccessGUDID}).\n\nKindly contact administrator.";
            errorMessage.Dump();
            break;
    }
    
}

private string ParenthesizeUDI(string unformattedString)
{
    return unformattedString.ToString().Remove(0, 2).Insert(0, "(01)");
}

private string ParenthesizeDateIdentifier(string unformattedString, int index)
{
    return unformattedString.ToString().Remove(index, 2).Insert(index, "(17)");
}

private string ParenthesizeSKUIdentifier(string unformattedString, int index)
{
    return unformattedString.ToString().Remove(index, 2).Insert(index, "(10)");
}

private string ParenthesizeLotIdentifier(string unformattedString, int index)
{
    return unformattedString.ToString().Remove(index, 2).Insert(index, "(20)");
}

private string Parenthesize30Identifier(string unformattedString, int index)
{
    return unformattedString.ToString().Remove(index, 2).Insert(index, "(30)");
}

Can I get a help on how to fix this issue?
